# Spring SimpleJDBCCall not quoting Oracle Procedure Name

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I am trying to use Spring's SimpleJdbcCall in order to execute a stored procedure in an Oracle database.

The stored procedure is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INBOUND_TST."p_INB_GetTimedoutBatch"
(
  mRecordSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ,mMinAttempt IN NUMBER
)
......
```

In my java code, I have this:

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbc)
    .withProcedureName("p_INB_GetTimedoutBatch")
    .returningResultSet("mRecordSet", new RowMapper<Retry>() {
        @Override
        public Retry mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            .... map row ....
        }
    })
    .execute(...MapSqlParameterSource...);
```

I get an error as below:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call "P_INB_GETTIMEDOUTBATCH"()}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'P_INB_GETTIMEDOUTBATCH' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I realise that this is happening because my procedure name is getting converted to a capital case and obviously this object does not exist in the database.

I am able to execute this when I use jdbcTemplate directly handling the callable statement creation myself and passing in the call string as **{call \"p_INB_GetTimedoutBatch\"(?,?)}**
Th
e missing quotes is the problem.

I have changed the SimpleJDBCCall code to pass the procedure name as \"p_INB_GetTimedoutBatch\" but it does not seem to have any effect and I get the same error.

Is this a bug in spring jdbc?

Comment: Try to create the procedure with uppercase name.

Comment: mm.. easier said than done. The procedure name is not something that can be changed easily. It works fine with Hibernate and also if called via plain jdbc template. Only the SimpleJdbcCall has issues.